# Problems with GET Graph API me/feed tags, picture, message

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a problem when publishing a post and tag people in it. When I add a picture to it, I can't tag people in the post; when I don't add the picture people get tagged. Has anyone experienced the same problem, yet? Thanks

P.S., Here is the example that is successfully posted but no one is tagged in it. If I leave out the picture field friends are actually tagged.

[image]

Comment: If you think this should work but it doesn’t – file a bug report. http://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: I just got notice from Facebook that this is a legit bug. They were able to reproduce it and are working on it.